# Couldn't understand an example used in explaining fundamental and derived quantities

Tags: soft-question, measurements, units

In my book under topic of fundamental and derived quantities, there is an example which is supposed to explain this concept and it goes like this,

> As a simple example, if a unit of length is defined, a unit of area is automatically obtained. If we make a square with its length equal to its breadth equal to the unit length, its area can be called the unit area. All areas can then be compared to this standard unit of area.

What I don't understand is that where is the numerical value that should be associated with the unit of length while saying about length and how can the 'area' of this square be a unit of area and also how it became standard as the example says in the last sentence and what does 'All areas can be compared to this standard unit of area'(the last sentence) supposed to mean. I am having a hard time understanding this example. I need assistance

Answer (score 3):

The metre, or the kilometre, or the mile, or any other unit of length is a product of humans (the Planck Units are an exception, though). You are free to “create” a new unit to measure length. For example, you may call the straight-line distance between the tip of your middle finger and the extreme-most point of your shoulder when your arm is extended “$1$ arm’s length”. This newly defined unit of length is no less valid than any other. Now, recognise that the unit of area is of the format: (unit of length)$^2$. Area can always be expressed as the product of two lengths. This is why if we define a unit of length, a unit of area is automatically obtained. Now, imagine a square with side length equal to $1$ arm’s length. The area of the square is $1$ (arm’s length)$^2$. This is a result of the fact that the area of a square of side length $s$ is equal to $s^2$, and $1^2=1$. The “numerical value that should be associated with the length” should be understood to be $1$ whenever we talk about a “unit length”. Similarly, the numerical value associated with a “unit area” is 1. The numerical value associated with a “unit ~quantity~” is 1.

Comment: @Heisenberg- Sorry for late response but please see my edited question.

Comment: Again, it all comes down to the fact that the area of a square of side length $a$ is $a^2$ and $1^2=1$. Make any square with a side length of $1$ unit. That $1$ unit may be [Graham’s Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) when expressed in metres for all we care. The area will always be $1 unit^2$. Of course if you want to express the area in $m^2$, you’ll have to find the square of the numerical value of the length while expressed in metres.

Comment: 2. As for comparing all other areas with a defined unit area, imagine a graph sheet. The smallest box in a graph sheet is usually a square with side length $0.1 cm$. For the sake of readability, I’ll let $u=0.1$. The area of that small box is $u^2 cm^2$. Now, draw any random closed curve on the graph sheet. Count precisely the number of the small squares the curve encloses. It need not be an integer. In fact, chances are it won’t be an integer. Say you count $x$ small squares. What is the area of this curve then? The area will be $xu^2 cm^2$.

Comment: 3. Now think about what I said about defining new units. I’ll define a new unit called the “graph unit”. I’ll define it like so: $1 gu=u cm=0.1 cm$. So, the length of the side of each of the small squares is precisely $1 gu$ and it’s area is precisely $1 gu^2$. Now, if you count up the number of squares any closed curve drawn on the graph encloses, and find it to be $n$ you can say that the area of the curve is $n gu^2$. This is essentially what comparing any area to the unit area means.

Comment: @Heisenberg- Thank you for speedy answer, I am trying to understand your main answer and the answer you gave in the comments and actually I misinterpreted my own example they actually said 'its area can be called the unit area' i took it as its area is the unit area..... my bad, sorry, but does this sentence mean that '1 (unit length)^2' is equal to 1 unit area' ?

Comment: Yes $1 (unit  length)^2$ is equal to $1 unit area$. Again, there is no universal law that says we have to compare all areas with areas of unit squares. If we so wish, we could’ve chosen the unit area to be the area of a unit circle, but I’m not going to explain this further since it may needlessly confuse you. Just know that it’s super convenient to compare areas with the area of a square of side length equal to $1$ unit, and that’s why we define $1 unit area$ as $1 (unit  length)^2$.